# Chrome "protocols must match" error when running Google Cloud Endpoints web client on localhost

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-endpoints

I use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to serve my web application on localhost. When I include `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>` on my index.html page, I get the following error in the console:

> Blocked a frame with origin "`https://accounts.google.com`" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "`http://127.0.0.1:9000`".  The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

I can't run my local server on https. How can I run my web application locally?

Comment: Start Chrome with flag --disable-web-security. That should do the job.

Comment: I tried `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security` and `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security`: same problem.

Comment: When I try the same on my Macbook, it works. On Windows 7 it doesn't. Both in Chrome.

Comment: On Windows 7 it works in Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the Chrome extension [DoNotTrackMe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/donottrackme-online-priva/epanfjkfahimkgomnigadpkobaefekcd) that was causing the error. Disabling the extension solves the problem.